# javax.faces.FacesException: PanelGrid without a 'columns' attribute expects at least one <p:row> element

Tags: jsf, primefaces

actualmente estoy migrando mi aplicacion de PrimeFaces 8 a la version 10, y me he encontrado con la siguiente exception: javax.faces.FacesException: PanelGrid ... without a 'columns' attribute expects at least one <p:row> element. En la version 8 de primefaces esto funciona perfectamente, pero en la versión 10 me arroja esta excepción, alguien con algún problema similar, y como lo resolvio....????

```
    <p:dialog ....>    
    
    <h:form ....>
       <p:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" rendered="#{peopleController.selected != null}">
                    <p:messages id="messages2"/>
                    <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="false" sticky="false"/>
                    <p:tabView activeIndex="#{peopleController.intTabViewIndex}" id="PeopleTabView" >
                        <p:tab title="Dat Básicos">
                            <p:panelGrid id="datBasicos"  columns="4" layout="grid" styleClass="ui-panelgrid-blank form-group" style="border:0px none;"    >                    
                                   <ui:include src="/include/people/peopleDta.xhtml"/>
....
```

Answer (score 0):

La excepción se ha presentado debido a que dentro de peopleDta.xhtml, existía nuevamente un panelGrid, he removido esto y se ha levantado la excepción.